DNS and PTR names for mail servers - best practice?
Should the hostname of the mail server you send mail from always have an rDNS (PTR type) of the same name?
I ask because I notice the name of my mail server doesn't have the same name as the PTR  record for its IP address, but is that of the MX record host name instead.
In which case, is it better to change my mail server's name, or ask my ISP to change the PTR for its address so they are the same?

The PTR record for a mail server is a very primitive sort of anti-spam measure, and while it's important enough to set it, it is no longer sufficient by any means. It is important that the main domain name is the same - e.g. for a domain domain.com, if the mailer is mail.domain.com but the PTR for that host is anything.domain.com, it will work.
It's much more important that your SPF records be correct and up to date, and that you implement as much of DKIM/DMARC as you can. It is SPF and DMARC that the big mailers use to verify your mail source.

OK thanks. I've got SPF records and DKIM signing, although Google's Postmaster Tools say that some (but oddly not all) domains have "From: header alignment" issues ("Ensure that the From: header aligns with either SPF or DKIM"). They don't say what the nature of this is, but I assume it's not this hostname/PTR thing? EDIT: I think it may be due to forwarding.
